# Preserve map order while unmarshalling bson data to a Golang map

Tags: mongodb, go

Mongo driver used: https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver

I have some data saved in the mongodb like below:

```
 {
        "title" : "elem_1_3_title",
        "list" : "elem_1_3_list"
 }
```

When I receive this data using mongodb driver then it sorts the map in the alphabetical order:

```
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
pages := make([]map[string]interface{})
err = cursor.All(context.TODO(), &pages)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
```

**output:**

```
{
    "list" : "elem_1_3_list",
    "title" : "elem_1_3_title"
}
```

**updated**:

```
type PageResp struct {
    Id            int                               `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Status        int                               `json:"status" bson:"status"`
    AddedSections []string                          `json:"added_sections" bson:"added_sections"`
    Sections        *orderedmap.OrderedMap            `json:"sections,omitempty" bson:"sections,omitempty"`
}
```

The data from database is received in this struct & sections field is the map which needs to be ordered.

**NOTE:** I can not define structs for this as I have a very long list of fields & some new fields can be added in the future.

Is there any possible way to receive the same order which is saved under mongodb ?

Comment: With a map the order is not guaranted. I recommand you to define a struct as huge is it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need an ordered map in order to preserve order.

See for instance [`elliotchance/orderedmap`](https://github.com/elliotchance/orderedmap) described in "[An Ordered Map in Go](https://medium.com/swlh/an-ordered-map-in-go-436634692381)".
Or [`wk8/go-ordered-map`](https://github.com/wk8/go-ordered-map) with Go 1.18 and parameter types.

In both instances, that would replace your `make([]map[string]interface{})`

```
om := orderedmap.New[string, string]()
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use this ordered map type for a field type in a struct? How can I do that ? Meaning how can I use this for map[string]map[string]interface{} ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur in your case, string would be the key, and the rest being the type of the value. I would define a type alias for the value type.

Comment: wk8/go-ordered-map is not woking, it says cant find package. you mean for map[string]map[string]interface{}, it would be m := orderedmap.NewOrderedMap[string, any]() ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur I would need to test it (but I am on my phone right now)

Comment: I have updated the post, could you please check that If its possible ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur Not tested, but you need a type alias with a Marshall/Unmarshall method, as in https://go.dev/play/p/LjOrp4k6lqf.

Comment: I dont need to to set the map keys like you did on playground. I know you added that for a complete example. But when I define a type alias then the data is not mapped from mongodb cursor to the defined type for a struct field.

Comment: Also it returned the addresses of the map values. How to get the actual value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245390/discussion-between-vonc-and-amandeep-kaur).